# Properly using HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap for a large app

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-sass

I've been using CSS for about 8 years - professionally for 1 year.  I'm comfortable with Bootstrap, Foundation, and Sass.  I get that Bootstrap is there to create website that 'adjust' and have consistent markup.  I've always been under the impression that every component should be able to stand alone and things should generally be targeted based on their location and given a class which groups common styles for prototyping.  Then when the layout is 'firmed up' classes can be consolidated/abstracted using sass to reflect the html node/context rather then the styles being applied.  Recently I've been asked to sandbox customization to 'my' tab and that we can sync up later.  While this has made programming across state lines easy my code is becoming polluted with !important because I can't override bootstrap in the sass.  The other team suggested I create custom variables rather then using the bootstrap one.

I never really know how to approach layout/theming and always feel like I'm wresting Bootstrap.  Particularly, I'm given a layout and asked to implement it (unresponsive for the moment) with bootstrap.  I do and it comes out with a deep html structure and lots of odd padding and margins.  Then I try to remedy this by adjusting padding based on context.  This is tedious, confusing, and results in a lot of markup and overrides.  The code is a pain to read and is in conflict with most of bootstrap's defaults.  Then UX refines our wire frames and I find myself doing lots of math and creating more 'edge cases'.

I've considered wiping all defaults at the app/tab/form level and setting the padding and margins in less places.  This would mean components can't stand individually. :(  It would be more of a case-by-case, bottom up approach.  Is this a better way to do things or do i just need to get UX to cut back on the 'edge cases' so I can write more generalized styles?

The other thing that confuses me is what responsive is.  I've always though of responsive as responding to page size to maintain/optimize it visually.  It seems like 'technically' it's using breakpoints - particularly everyone seems to want this handled by a library.  I usually end up combining these to create a base layout that responds a bit then adding more bootstrap for alternate layouts.  It's bitten me a few times.  UX dept gets new employees who feel that larger inputs imply more data needed or that by having the second column of boxes further from the first things feel too spread out (both kinda true).  Is this a bad practice?  A past interviewer also went off on me for the approach (taken with a grain of salt as she claimed CSS6 was the norm).  Does anyone else combine subtle stretching with full layout changes.  Is this really a bad practice?

How deeply do you ingrain bootstrap into your layout?  Like I mentioned, I've tried to integrate it all the way down into the form and it's been a headache.  Do you typically only use it at the high level?

The other thing that frustrates me is how poorly Bootstrap and Flexbox work together.  The app i'm currently working on has a static height with scrollable panels.  I suggested Foundation for Apps but we had to go with Bootstrap as it was already used by many of the sister apps.  I'm now stuck using bootstrap to layout the shared header and tab components, then JS to calculate the height of columns (so it's set statically), then flexbox to manage the height of their content, then bootstrap again to manage the layout of that content.  The JS calculations don't pair well with Angular's rendering and digest cycle at all.  It works, but it's sensitive to change.  I'd love to make it all Flexbox (or height managed Bootstrap).  Is the best approach to try to convince us to add a lightweight flexbox based grid to live in harmony with bootstrap?  Or is this going to need to be a full transition? :/ We use form-group and a lot of the css and variables at this point.

I know it's a lot of questions - they have been piling up for a while. :p Hopefully some of you guys can help me get this all straitened out in my head. :) Thanks!